# Javascript indexOf string with escaping

Tags: javascript, escaping, indexof

I'm trying to detect if part of a string exists, with:

```
if (loopCache.indexOf('<ul class=\"bullet-list-round\">') > -1){ }
```

Where the whole string as an example is:

```
 var loopCache = 'Active Life<ul class=\"bullet-list-round\">';
```

indexOf won't detect at all, probably due to escape issues?

Comment: Testing in Chrome's console, that works perfectly for me. Are you sure your strings are the same?

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/3v89rrgd/

Comment: Work perfectly for me too.

Comment: It will be a case that `loopCache` is a string where the quotes are escaped with \ - rather than running that second line which actually produced a string without the slashes.  For the same reason you'd need to escape the slashes in `.indexOf('...class=\\"foo\\"')` to ensure you are looking for the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

From Digigizmo's comment, the answer was to escape the escaped characters:

```
if (loopCache.indexOf('<ul class=\\"bullet-list-round\\">') > -1){  }
```